# jQuery CSS Selector combined with "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to figure out if something like this would be possible. We are given that HTML structure

```
<a href='#' class='anyLink'>
     <!-- here goes some content-->
    <div class='childElement'><!-- here goes some content--></div>
</a>
```

I am not able to use ID's because there are many links and it's not defined how many more are to come. So my question is, do you guys know a way where I can do something like this :

```
$('a').on("click",function(e){
    $(this +"div").val(); // for example.
});
```

I want to select a children element of that anchor that has been clicked or want to get the value of the children element. I also don't have any ID's of the children elements and I am trying to select things via CSS Selectors as `td:nth-child(4)`.
Could anybody tell me if this is possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
$('a').on("click",function(e){
    $("div",this).text(); // for example.
});
```

Comment: I like and use the second suggestion.

Comment: @EvilP: If this was helpful, be sure to accept this answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').on("click",function(e){
    $(this).children("div").eq(0).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a function called [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children).

But you can also try something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function( e ) {
  $('div', this).val(); // Each div child of this element
  $(this).children('div'); // Each div child of this element
});
```

Comment: sorry but I'm alery aware of .children. I have to access via css-selectors

Comment: You can use selectors as first parameter of children. [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/NvwMg/)